# Radius of curvature of a spherical mirror using only magnification?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

Given that an object of heigh 1cm is placed in front of a spherical mirror and produces an upright image of height 0.2cm, find the radius of curvature of the mirror.

I know that 
$ M = \frac{h_i}{h_o} = \frac{-i}{o}$

and

$ \frac{2}{R} = \frac{1}{o} + \frac{1}{i}$

Substituting the first equation into the second I get
$\frac{2}{R} = \frac{1}{o} - \frac{1}{oM}$

But I have no idea how I would find R without knowing the object distance o.